# Basically, I want to edit a html file in the Jenkins workspace which is generated after built. Tried few Jenkins Plugins, but no use

Tags: jenkins

Basically, I want to edit a html file in the Jenkins workspace which is generated after built.

Tried few Jenkins Plugins, but no use.

Basically, I want to edit a html file in the Jenkins workspace which is generated after built.

Tried few Jenkins Plugins, but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Basically i have used sed command in Jenkins using Shell Execute. I could be able to replace any string.
Thanks